# Can I log socket.io debug information to a file?

Tags: node.js, logging, socket.io

I'm running node.js with socket.io and I'd like to log the debug information (the information that shows in the node.js console when you run socket.io with default options) to a file, is there any way to do this?

Comment: Did you try setting logger with a file stream ?

Comment: try with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8393636/node-log-in-a-file-instead-of-the-console