# Console.dir - Nodejs redirect to a file

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, console

How can i redirect the `console.dir(obj)` output to a file instead of the console? 
I considered overwriting console.dir (with my custom fn.)to use file stream instead of stdout stream but the logic to walk down the object tree scares me.

Note: My node process is launched indirectly by emacs editor, so i cant use pipe to redirect any output.

Comment: i have said, i cant access stdout as my node process is a child process of emacs process

Comment: have you seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8393636/node-log-in-a-file-instead-of-the-console  ?

Comment: overwriting console.log is doable as what goes in as an arg, comes out... console.dir is not the same...

Comment: ok, then sorry. Cannot help here ((

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`console.dir` is just a wrapper around `util.inspect` that uses its default arguments.

```
console.log(util.inspect(myObj));
```

So you could simply do

```
var fs = require('fs');
function logToFile(input){
    fs.writeFile('.log', util.inspect(input));
}
```

Comment: had to use `fs.writeFileSync` with those arguments, but works great!