# Node, redirect console to a file

Tags: node.js, output

How can I redirect everything what is displayed in console to a file?
I mean for example, i call some function, this function display something on console (no metter if it is `console.log` or `process.stdout.write`)?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node: log in a file instead of the console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8393636/node-log-in-a-file-instead-of-the-console)

Comment: i tried with it but it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

While not strictly a Node.js answer, you could achieve this at the shell level. For example if you are using bash, you could redirect both standard output and error stream to a file using the following

```
#!/bin/bash
node app.js &> output.log
```

Check out also `tee` command for simultaneous output to both file and screen.