# Create Log file in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, logging, npm, mocha.js, chai

How to create and save a log file in NodeJS for testing purpose?
The log file should contain the success/failure ratio of tests conducted.
I haven't tried anything yet as I am new to NodeJs.

Comment: success/failure ratio or success/failed messages ?

Comment: you can use loggers like winston

Comment: Close duplicate of
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8393636/node-log-in-a-file-instead-of-the-console

Answer (score 12):

Firstly do you know about [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/)?
If No, then read/research about it.
Else, then good. Look out for npm-modules suitable for logging task.
I shall recommend you [winston-logger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston).

Install winston in your project as:

```
npm install winston --save
```

Here's a configuration ready to use out-of-box that I use frequently in my projects as logger.js under utils.

```
 /**
 * Configurations of logger.
 */
const winston = require('winston');
const winstonRotator = require('winston-daily-rotate-file');

const consoleConfig = [
  new winston.transports.Console({
    'colorize': true
  })
];

const createLogger = new winston.Logger({
  'transports': consoleConfig
});

const successLogger = createLogger;
successLogger.add(winstonRotator, {
  'name': 'access-file',
  'level': 'info',
  'filename': './logs/access.log',
  'json': false,
  'datePattern': 'yyyy-MM-dd-',
  'prepend': true
});

const errorLogger = createLogger;
errorLogger.add(winstonRotator, {
  'name': 'error-file',
  'level': 'error',
  'filename': './logs/error.log',
  'json': false,
  'datePattern': 'yyyy-MM-dd-',
  'prepend': true
});

module.exports = {
  'successlog': successLogger,
  'errorlog': errorLogger
};
```

And then simply import wherever required as this:

```
const errorLog = require('../util/logger').errorlog;
const successlog = require('../util/logger').successlog;
```

Then you can log the success as:

```
successlog.info(`Success Message and variables: ${variable}`);
```

and Errors as:

```
errorlog.error(`Error Message : ${error}`);
```

It also logs all the success-logs and error-logs in a file under logs directory date-wise as you can see here.
[image: log direcotry]

I have used "accesslog" instead of "successlog" as a keyword in my project.
And I didn't get what you meant about 'success/failure ratio'.
In order to get the ratio simply count the no. of times success and error logs are logged.

Comment: I am using the exact configurations, but the log file is not generated. I see the logs in the console.

Comment: Is it possible to use it in ES Modules? I mean, with .mjs files

Comment: @MartínJF Well theoretically It should work if you map the `require` and `module.exports` correctly to `import` and `export` although I haven't worked on `.mjs` or `.cjs` based approaches. Try out and let us know. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
require('mkdirp').sync('logs') // your log directory

var logger = require('log4js')

logger.configure({
    "appenders": [{
        "type": "console"
    }, {
        "type": "dateFile",
        "category": "log",
        "filename": "logs/exp",
        "pattern": "yyMMdd.log",
        "alwaysIncludePattern": true
    }],
    "replaceConsole": true
})

logger.info('success')
logger.error('fail')
```

Comment: try to add some explanation maybe? code-only answer are not very helpful in general. also, this doesn't answer OP question, it'll just forward everything to a file.