# Logging variable in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have a variable named, 'res'. This variable if used with `console.log()` print all request to a function. My question is... How to log this variable in a log.txt file?

Example using `console.log(res)`

Print in console:

```
[ 'AndroidShareANE',
  'pixi.js',
  'ShortSword',
  'faceshiftparser',
  'clmutils',
  'chaikin-smooth',
  'getuservideo',
  'getboundingbox',
  'clmdraw',
  'SpriteSheetScrubberTutorial',
  'interpolation-arrays',
```

This is a one part of response.

My purpose is log in `log.txt` file the `var` content. Identical to `console.log()` result.

Thanks for your collaboration, and sorry my bad english.

Comment: 'var' is a reserved word.  You shouldn't use it as a variable name.

Comment: Sorry, my variable is 'res'.

Comment: this question may be duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8393636/node-log-in-a-file-instead-of-the-console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to create a new Console object that writes to your file. [The docs](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_new_console_stdout_stderr) have an example of this exact thing, which I'll reproduce here for posterity:

> ```
> const output = fs.createWriteStream('./stdout.log');
> const errorOutput = fs.createWriteStream('./stderr.log');
> // custom simple logger
> const logger = new Console(output, errorOutput);
> // use it like console
> var count = 5;
> logger.log('count: %d', count);
> // in stdout.log: count 5
> ```

If you don't pass the second argument (`errorOutput`) to `new Console` then the error output will also be written to the `output` file.

Comment: Mhm, and my variable 'var' containing result, where is located?

Comment: In the above code `logger` is an instance of Console, just like `console` in `console.log`. You give your variable as an argument to `logger.log`, just like you did with `console.log`.

Comment: Please, give me a example for this.

Comment: `logger.log(var)`.

Comment: See "ReferenceError: Console is not defined" error.

Comment: You need to `require('console')` (and assign it to a variable named `Console`) just like any other Node.js module.

Comment: TypeError: Console is not a constructor

Comment: Looking more closely at the docs, the Console constructor is a property of the `console` module, so you'll want to do e.g. `const Console = require('console').Console`.