# NodeJS ExpressJS - how to log errors for the production server?

Tags: node.js, express, error-log

How can I log any errors from ExpressJS apps into a file?

I know I can log a Slim framework easily with [monolog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog):

```
$app->get('/tickets', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    $this->logger->addInfo("Something interesting happened");

    $mapper = new Simon\TicketMapper($this->db);
    $tickets = $mapper->getTickets();

    $response->getBody()->write(var_export($tickets, true));
    return $response;
});
```

In Express, I usually log the error to console for **development**:

```
Model.findOne(options, function(err, doc) {

    var output = {};
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error retrieving doc: " + err);
    }
```

But in my **production** server, I do need a helpful log file when the app goes wrong.

Any ideas?

In Express's `app.js`, it has this:

```
// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {

  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: err
    });
  });

}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});
```

But how do I turn the production's one on? Is it the same as monolog that I need?

Comment: Should be as simple as outputting the error to a file instead of the console so that you can reference this file. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8393636/node-log-in-a-file-instead-of-the-console

Answer (score 13):

[winston](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston) is a popular library for logging.

You can transport all logs to one file or keep different files for error, debug and info logs.

Example:

```
  var winston = require('winston');

  var logger = new winston.Logger({
    level: 'error',
    transports: [
      new (winston.transports.File)({ filename: 'error.log' })
    ]
  });
```

In the code:

```
logger.log('error', 'test error message %s', 'my string');
```

You can also use [winston daily rotate file](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston-daily-rotate-file) with winston to rotate your log files based on size or date.

Answer (score 4):

You can either add a logging library like [morgan](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan) or if you have your node app running under a process manager, like pm2, then pm2 will keep track of the logging for you. I haven't used pm2 a ton, but from what I understand you could keep you `console.log` statements the same and pm2 will save all the output from your app into log files for you. You can read more about pm2's logging capabilities [here](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/log-management/).

Comment: I use PM2. But I prefer having a logger like monolog that I can manage it manually inside my code.

Answer (score 0):

> you may feel irrelevant as **PM2** is process manager but i found
>   **PM2** also best to deal error loggs.

Answer (score 0):

If you're fine with logging the errors to your database instead of a log file, check out npm library grackle_tracking https://www.npmjs.com/package/grackle_tracking
It allows you to log to the console, catch & log caught and uncaught errors to the database. It also has the ability to track all your traffic.