# How to see console.logs in production environment?

Tags: node.js, putty

Im recently pushing my app to production, however stuff that worked localy dont work on production. Issue is the backend, I'm using node.js and I need to locate the source of the problem. However I don't know how to see my console.logs. Tried using putty, but I don't see anything.

What can I do?

Comment: you can write logs in file on daily basis

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NodeJS ExpressJS - how to log errors for the production server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43054203/nodejs-expressjs-how-to-log-errors-for-the-production-server)

Comment: This is a hard to answer question as it depends almost entirely on your server set up. Some cloud services will have a way to view the console output of node, but in general you may be running it as a background process. The best thing to do is to write logs to a file which you would then be able to read if you ssh to the server (or ftp or whatever you are doing).

Answer (score 2):

It depends of the library that you using, if you are using **pm2** then type:

```
pm2 logs
```

If you using **forever** type:

```
 forever describe app
```

and you will get the file paths for error.log and output.log

Comment: Both of these libraries are unrelated to the OP and do not answer the question.

Comment: PM2 is a production process manager for Node.js applications. It allows you to keep applications alive forever. How does this libraries are unrelated to the question?! Most of nodejs applications in production environment uses one of this two libraries.