# How to store nodejs server runtime error logs in file winston nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, winston, express-winston

I am new to winston and trying to store nodejs server logs into file.

```
const {
    createLogger,
    transports,
    format
} = require('winston');

const logger = createLogger({
    transports: [
        new transports.File({
            filename : 'info.log',
            level: 'info',
            format: format.combine(format.timestamp(), format.json())
        })
    ]
})

module.exports = logger;
```

And I can store log in the file using `logger.log('info',"Inside /login")`

How can I store the nodejs server logs which are generated automatically run time when error happens.

For example this log which I can see in console when the mySQL db connection was closed and these logs were generated by nodejs server.

[image]

Comment: You question already answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/43054361/10526425

Comment: It doesn't answer my question as it is writing `logger.log('error', 'test error message %s', 'my string');` but here I have mentioned the logs I want in the file are generated dynamically. Check the example I have provided in the question.

Comment: One of the way to do is override the method which is called when the logs are displayed on console and store it in file as on production we don't have console.

Comment: It doesn't answer my question as it is writing `logger.log('error', 'test error message %s', 'my string');` but here I have mentioned the logs I want in the file are generated dynamically/unexpected errors while using in production. Check the example I have provided in the question.