# Can I capture the console output in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, kill

I am trying to kill a process at first, I executed with

```
exec  = require('child_process').exec;
exec('kill xxx', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    if (error) {
        console.log('exec error: ', error);
    }else{
       console.log(stdout)
    }
});
```

I noticed the kill program probably started a child process, whose output cannot be captured here as stdout.

So can I generally capture these console output which seem to be not very relevant with the code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node: log in a file instead of the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8393636/node-log-in-a-file-instead-of-the-console)

Comment: If you want to truly "catch them all" you may output everything to a file with "npm run dev > log.txt" and then create an external app/script to process the dumped text to a dashboard or redirect the text to a remote logger

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Stolen: [Node: log in a file instead of the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8393636/node-log-in-a-file-instead-of-the-console)

```
var fs = require('fs');
var util = require('util');
var log_file = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/debug.log', {flags : 'w'});
var log_stdout = process.stdout;

console.log = function(d) { //
  log_file.write(util.format(d) + '\n');
  log_stdout.write(util.format(d) + '\n');
};
```

**ANSWER #2**
*This message is not created by console.log rather just the Linux system itself. How to catch this?*

I think you should be able to do something with fs like so...

```
  var fs = require('fs');
  var util = require('util');
  var log_file = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/debug.log', {flags : 'w'});
  var log_stdout = process.stdout;

const command = 'node your_node_script'; //Whatever you would run in terminal

cp.exec(command, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if(error) {
        log_file.write(error);

    }
    if(stdout) {
        log_file.write(stdout);
    }
    if(stderr) {
        log_file.write(stderr);
    }
});
```

Comment: hmm, the problem is. The console output is not necessary created by console.log. E.g. when I killed a process, wait for 2 s, then the console will generate a message "xxx terminated". This message is not created by console.log rather just the Linux system itself. How to catch this?

Comment: Updated answer with a suggestion to try.

Comment: it's partiatly works, but doesn't show second argument fro console.log with varibale, only text data quoted