# Listen to (own) process.stdout (in Node.js)

Tags: node.js, io, stream, stdout

Probably a basic question for those familiar with the topic. Consider the following toy program:

```
  const fs = require('fs');
  process.stdout.on('data', (chunk) => {
    fs.writeFileSync('myfile.txt', chunk, 'utf-8'); // just an example
  });
  process.stdout.write('xyz');
```

If I run this code just as it is, I get the following error:

```
  errno: -4053,
  code: 'ENOTCONN',
  syscall: 'read'
```

I already do not understand why that happens. But it gets even stranger:

*When I run the code with a `console.log()` before it, no error is thrown anymore*! However, the listener I defined for the `data` event seems not to be executed in that case, as no text file is created.

Can someone explain to me why this happens and what I can do get the expected result (here write to myfile.txt)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first error you see is caused by trying to connect to `stdout` to get its `data`. You haven't written anything to `stdout`, so it's not initialized, so you can't connect to it! `ENOTCONN` means exactly that: `Error: Not Connected` (to the `stdout` socket).

Now, for the second error. `console.log()` is an alias for `process.stdout.write('\n')`. So when you run the code with a `console.log()` before it, you've now initialized `stdout`, so you can connect to it and no `ENOTCONN` error will be thrown. But you're waiting for input to come from the console from `stdout`. **Input doesn't come from `stdout`; it comes from `stdin`.**

To fix this, you need to:

1. Initialize `stdin` before connecting to it, using `process.stdin.resume()`.
2. Wait for `data` from `stdin` rather than `stdout`, using `process.stdin.on(...)`.
3. Exit the program successfully when you're done receiving input from `stdin`, using `process.exit(0)`.

```
const fs = require('fs')

process.stdin.resume()
process.stdin.on('data', (chunk) => {
  fs.writeFileSync('mytestfile.txt', chunk, 'utf-8')

  // Uncomment the following line if you want to write
  // something to the console to indicate success
  // process.stdout.write("Got your input!")

  process.exit(0)
})
```

Comment: so is there no way to catch the result of all the things that are getting printed on console and write them in the file? imagine we write console.log('foo') and our code catch foo and write it in our file.

Comment: If you're asking about capturing console output from only this Node program, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47658413/can-i-capture-the-console-output-in-node-js gives a couple good answers!

Answer (score 0):

The error you're seeing is occurring because the **data** event is not being emitted by the `process.stdout` stream. This means that the listener you've defined is not being called, and thus the `writeFileSync` call is not being executed.

As for why adding a `console.log()` resolves the issue, it's likely that the `console.log` call is causing the event loop to run, which in turn causes the **data** event to be emitted.

In order to get the expected result of writing to **myfile.txt**, you should try using the '**end**' event instead of the '**data**' event. This event is emitted when there is no more data to be read from the stream.

Try this:

```
process.stdout.on('end', () => {
    fs.writeFileSync('myfile.txt', 'xyz', 'utf-8');
});
process.stdout.end();
```

This will write the string 'xyz' to **myfile.txt** when the '**end**' event is emitted.
Another alternative would be to directly write to the file before the **stdout.write()**

```
fs.writeFileSync('myfile.txt', 'xyz', 'utf-8');
process.stdout.write('xyz');
```

Either way, it will ensure that your file is written before the process exits.