# Create log file in angular 2

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, client

I have to create a log file in angular 2 to keep tracking of function executed. Can anyone suggest some ways to append the logs in a file and the file has to store in the project folder? 
I have tried angular2-txt and saveAs in JS, both are downloads the file for each execution of command. But i need just append all the execution command text in a file which is in the local folder.

All the logs are to be in file and it need to be only at client side.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Client side angular cannot access local folders/files. Pass logs over a service and a server side code (using node.js for e.g. refer: [Node: log in a file instead of the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8393636/node-log-in-a-file-instead-of-the-console)) to write it to a file.