# Loopback strong-error-handler and log errors to file

Tags: logging, loopbackjs

I cannot understand how can I configure Loopback to store strong-error-handler output to a file with a proper logging strategy.

Answer (score 2):

There're two parts to be handled here. First, we need to grab the errors. This can be done easily, passing a layer/middleware intercepting the error as described [here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Using-strong-error-handler.html) by the official documentation

Second, we've to pass those errors to our logging file. Handsome folks have already done it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8393636/node-log-in-a-file-instead-of-the-console), too. Some are recommending Winston while others are doing it by their hands, as for educational purposes, let's use the native way.

`error-logger.js`

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');
const logFile = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/debug.log', {flags: 'w'});
const logStdout = process.stdout;

module.exports = function(options) {
  return function logError(err, req, res, next) {
    console.log('unhandled error', err);
    logFile.write(util.format(err) + '\n');
    logStdout.write(util.format(err) + '\n');
    next(err);
  };
};
```

Don't forget about middleware.

`server/middleware.json`

```
{
  // ...
  "final:after": {
    "./middleware/error-logger": {},
    "strong-error-handler": {
      "params": {
        "log": false
      }
    }
}
```