# Dump all console javascript outputs as string

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a problem I need to get all console.log outputs is it possible to dump all console.log outputs to a one variable? I use node.js. A little bit of context: I have an output of mocha reporter and I want to have all output to format it and send it via email

Comment: Probably possible, but pretty weird, can you give a bit more context?

Comment: Better write them in a log file?

Comment: I add a context

Comment: Possibly dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8393636/node-log-in-a-file-instead-of-the-console

Comment: I don't want to create log file

Comment: You shouldn't even use `console.log` and now you actually want to use it to collect log information in order to send it via email? What on earth are you working on?

Comment: I need it because i need to send the html optimized output of mocha reporter and we don't use any CI. I don't really see better solution only for example made my custom reporter but it's much more work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the answer of @godot:

```
var logs = '' // logs needs to be defined for the += operator
const tmp = console.log
console.log = function(...args) {
  // string substitution, console.log style
  const formatArg = util.format(...args)
  logs += formatArg + '\n'
  tmp(...args)
}

// To test it :

console.log('test1')
// use console.log with the "printf" style
console.log('test%d', 2)
// same
console.log('%s%d', 'test', 3)
// now show all the logs that were collected in the global var logs variable
console.log('logs: ', logs) // if you don't like globals, u can also use put it in an attribute of the console object...
```

Comment: Sure, I only added the `util.format` function which implement the "string substitution" that console.log is using.
Look [here](https://millermedeiros.github.io/mdoc/examples/node_api/doc/util.html#util.format) for the explanation but if you know C, it is very similar to the famous `printf` function.

Comment: The [rest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) operator (`...`) in the parameters of the function *definition*) and the [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) operator (`...`) in the argument of a function *call*) is allowing you to respectively gather together and spread all the arguments of a function into/from one variable (an array to be precise).
Here as we don't know the number of arguments of the console.log function we are trying to reproduce, it is super convenient!

Comment: I meant: edit the answer and explain your code, code only answers are flagged as low quality answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a kind of hack where you substitute console.log with another function following a kind of [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern):

```
var logs = ''; // logs needs to be defined for the += operator
const tmp = console.log;
console.log = function(...args){ 
    logs += arg + ' '
    tmp(...args)
}
```

Obviously, using a global variable is not great but you can improve from there...

Comment: I will try and let you know

Comment: It's strange but now i have output like this: `%d passing (%ss) %d failing undefined %s) %s:
%s%s
%s`

Comment: Your message is a bit cryptic... What output are you expecting?
Regarding the `undefined`, it's normal. I don't know if you noticed but I had changed my code to remove the problem.

Comment: normally it look like this `2 passing (24.20s)
1 failing` the %d and %s it think needed to replace it with data but it break only if redefine `console.log`

Comment: Ok it's because your logger is using string substitution... See if my correction is getting you closer to where you want (you'll have to implement a string sub yourself in order to finish the job).

Comment: I think I'm very near now the normal console output doesn't breaks but if I try to output logs, even in normal output string substitution breaks.  Even if try to output like this `let final = logs; console.log(final);'. (didn't saw your edit will try to implement by my self)