# Save a console.log to a text file on local machine

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript file (file.js) that contains the following code:

`console.log("Hello World!")`

When I run this code in my terminal `node file.js`, I get the following output:

`Hello World`

If I wanted to save this to a file programmatically (not right clicking and clicking save), does anyone know how I can do that?

The only solution I can find on the internet was using `JSON.stringify("Hello World!")`, but this doesn't do anything I don't believe (doesn't even output an error).

Reference: [How to save the output of a console.log(object) to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849562/how-to-save-the-output-of-a-console-logobject-to-a-file)

Comment: If you mean from outside your program, you can just do `node file.js >output.txt`. If you mean from inside your program, look into some `fs` methods.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Configure Node.js to log to a file instead of the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8393636/configure-node-js-to-log-to-a-file-instead-of-the-console)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to overwrite `console.log` with your own implementation that writes the values it's called with to a file.

```
const { appendFileSync } = require('fs');
const origConsole = globalThis.console;
const console = {
    log: (...args) => {
        appendFileSync('./logresults.txt', args.join('\n') + '\n');
        return origConsole.log.apply(origConsole, args);
    }
}

console.log("Hello World!");
console.log("another line", "yet another line");
```

If you called this frequently enough such that the sync writes are a problem, you could use `appendFile` or `fs.promises.appendFile` so that the writes don't block and use a queue for the pending values to write.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that your `console.log()` is some kind of text output you get from somewhere, so i made a randomstring gen function just to exemplify.

You just need to use the `fs` module from Node, then write the file to your system.

Like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');

const randomString = () => {
  return Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
};


const createFile = (fileName, content) => {
    fs.writeFile(fileName, content, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('The file has been saved!');
    });
}

createFile('test.txt', randomString());
```

Just note that if you're receiving text from an iteration, you maybe wanna insert '\n' on the end of each iteration to break the line on your text file.